# Can a newly sprouted avocado pit survive despite dehydration?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, roots, avocado, sprouting

This may be a weird question, but maybe somebody has any advice.
I had success with growing an avocado plant by suspending an avocado pit in water. The roots started growing about 2 weeks ago - after months of waiting. I was out of town over the weekend and when I came back, the pit layed next to it's bottle with water. (it usually sits on top) Turns out my father accidently pushed it down and it was laying there for over 24 hours, with the roots being exposed to the air. The roots were really brown and shriveled up. I put them back in water and the roots kinda soaked up with water again (the shrivelling went away), but they are still brown and didn't grow anymore. Usually you can watch them grow every single day, but now there is 0 progress.
My question now is, if anyone got a similiar experience and knows if the roots can make it? Or if anyone knows how I can save that little guy. I don't really have a green thumb, so I was very excited when I started seeing results :(

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've abandoned it at this point, but hopefully not! I had something similar happen to one recently, brown, shrivelled and still short at that point. I kept it in water for a while longer (a few weeks I think) and then two new roots started growing out of the old brown one. Since then it's grown a lot more too and is looking pretty healthy overall, though the original brown root is still there.